# Javascript regular expressions evaluating to both true and false

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to learn how to test regular expressions and I'm a little confused. Below is a test for a whether word letters are in a regular expression or not. If they are they should write to a substring, and if they are not (! and . and " ") they should dump to writing the previously recorded substring in an array. However, word.test(str) is equalling both false and true when testing in the loop! When I test it on it's own it evaluates fine (example after ****), but there is some weird thing going on where it doesn't work in a for loop. Any ideas?

```
 function countWords(str) {
      var testString = '';
      var stringArray = [];
      var retObj = {};
      var word = /\S/;

  for(i = 0; i<str.length; i++)
  {
      if (word.test(str[i]) === true);
      {
          testString = testString.concat(str[i]);
      }
      if (word.test(str[i]) === false);
      {
          stringArray = stringArray + "," + testString;
          testString = "";
      }
  }

  return stringArray;

}

console.log(countWords("Hi! How are you?"));


console.log("*****");

var phrase = "Hi! How are you?";
console.log(/\S/.test(phrase[3]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (word.test(str[i]) === true);`

If the test is true, do nothing (`;`)

```
  {
      testString = testString.concat(str[i])
  }
```

Then execute this compound statement.

```
  if (word.test(str[i]) === false);
```

If the test is false, do nothing again (`;`).

```
  {
      stringArray = stringArray + "," + testString;
  }
```

Then do this compound statement.

Your assignments are not consequences of the `if` statements, they're just freestanding, because of the extra semicolons.